# Stopping Powershell command after certain amount of time

Tags: powershell

I would like to find out how to stop a Powershell command (Invoke-VMscript) and continue in the program after a certain amount of time has passed. (Preferably not using jobs)

Comment: There are too many ways to achieve this to give an answer based on the information you gave us (no own effort or code example). However, I can't think of any way to do this in a single thread (so using jobs, a backgroundworker, timer object, runspaces etc seem like a minimal requirement)

Answer (score 0):

You can add timer/event in your command. Below is the example of self-terminating script

```
$timer = New-Object timers.timer
$timer.Interval = 10000 # milliseconds
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier Timer.Output -Action {Write-Host "Timeout!"; Stop-Process $pid}
$timer.Enabled = $true

# do something

while ($true) {

    sleep 1
    Write-Host (get-date)

}
```